# Mysql/Laravel : Using left join to fetch latest created at date of any employee

Tags: mysql, laravel

[image: Database Structure]

I'm trying to get all sections and their latest `created_at` using left join

I'm using below query

```
select es.*, sul.created_at as created_at from section as es 
left join section_update_logs as sul on es.id = sul.section_id 
where sul.emp_id = 3 
group by es.id 
order by es.id, sul.created_at asc;
```

the obvious output of the query is only show that records where `emp_id` is `3`, but i want all the records of `section` table, if there is no employee record in `section_update_logs` there should be a null/empty created_at.

Desired output is :

1. all rows of table `section`
2. `created_at` date if `sul.section_id` = `section.id` and `emp_id` = of particular employee.

Laravel Query :

```
$result = DB::table("section as es")
                ->select('es.*', 'sul.created_at')
                ->leftJoin('section_update_logs as sul', 'es.id', '=', 'sul.section_id')
                ->orderBy('es.weight')
                ->orderBy('sul.created_at')
                ->orWhere('sul.emp_id', $emp_id)
                ->groupBy('es.id')
                ->get();
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a closure to the [`leftJoin`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_leftJoin) function to add more conditions.

```
$result = DB::table("section as es")
    ->select('es.*', DB::raw('MAX(sul.created_at)'))
    ->leftJoin('section_update_logs as sul', function ($join) use ($emp_id) {
        $join->on('es.id', '=', 'sul.section_id')
            ->where('sul.emp_id', $emp_id);
    })
    ->orderBy('es.weight')
    ->orderBy('sul.created_at')
    ->groupBy('es.id')
    ->get();
```

This way, the filter on `sul.emp_id` is only validated when a relation is found.

To get the same result with your sql query, add a second condition to your join using `AND`:

```
select es.*, MAX(sul.created_at) as created_at from section as es 
left join section_update_logs as sul on es.id = sul.section_id AND sul.emp_id = 3 -- HERE
group by es.id 
order by es.id, sul.created_at asc;
```

Comment: Thanks it's working.
how can I get the same result with mysql query ? 
Could you please mention the query.

Comment: I have added the sql equivalent to my answer

Comment: there is one little problem i'm facing, order by sul.created_at is not working, as i need latest date, but this is showing the first entry of particular employee

Comment: yes its because adding groupby in builder object he should added in collection object

Comment: If you want the latest `created_at` date, you should use the `max()` function in your SQL query. I have added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use first since you are to display the result of a particular employee

```
$search = $request->input('id'); 
$data['result'] = DB::table("section")
   ->where('emp_id', $search)
   ->leftJoin('section_update_logs', 'section.id', '=', 'section_update_logs.section_id')
   ->orderBy('section_update_logs.created_at','desc')
   ->first();
   return view('viewblade', $data)
```

on your view

```
{{ $result ->name }}
 ...
```